Global configuration to store all enums as string even if they are defined as nullable
I want to have a global configuration in my DBContext to save all Enums in my model as string in the data store, the constraint is I need the config to work even if the Enum is nullable
I already found this solution but only works when the Enums are non-nullable.
protected override void ConfigureConventions(ModelConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder)
{
  configurationBuilder.Properties<Enum>().HaveConversion<string>();
}

My expectation is to define a generic rule/config without having to write a specific conversion for each possible Enum in the model.
Update:
I've already tried without any success these:
configurationBuilder.Properties<Enum?>().HaveConversion<string?>();
configurationBuilder.Properties<Enum?>().HaveConversion<string>();
It throws a System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' when inserting or querying data from the data store.

Have you tried configurationBuilder.Properties<Enum?>().HaveConversion<string?>(); assuming nullable reference types?

@HereticMonkey of course I did, it throws an exception.

The thing is that Enum? is Nullable<Enum> and Nullable<SomeConcreteEnum> is not  Nullable<Enum> while SomeConcreteEnum is Enum.

Enums are easier to deal with if you assign "meaning" to the default; i.e. Undefined = 0. Nullables are not your friend when there are other options.

This worked for me:
configurationBuilder.Properties<Enum>().HaveConversion<string?>();

My schema has the column defined as a null-able NVARCHAR(50) for instance and I can store a row with an enumeration value (which converts to string) and a #null value which leaves the column as the default #null.
The test entity I had:
[Table("Projects")]
public class Project
{
    [Key]
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public TestEnums? TestEnum { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Job> Jobs { get; protected set; } = [];
}

public enum TestEnums
{
    None = 0,
    Something,
    SomethingElse
}

and the test:
[Test]
public void TestInsert()
{
    using var context = new AltDbContext();
    var project = new Project { Name = "TestNew" };
    context.Projects.Add(project);
    context.SaveChanges();
}

Wrote a record successfully with the #null for the TestEnum column.
Not sure about code-first if you want it to create the column as a null-able string, but if you have an existing schema it works with a null-able column just fine.

Unfortunately it's not a solution for my case, I'm using MongoDB and I'm letting EF to deal with the model definition/creation based of my Entities so adding a custom column type for each possible Enum will end in the same way of adding a custom conversion for each Enum column

Not sure I follow. MongoDB may complicate things depending on that provider implementation (no idea why anyone wants to use an ORM over a NoSQL document store) but the config that did work for me was Properties<Enum>().HaveConversion<string?> to get a null-able enum property stored as a null-able string. (Note the Properties is non-nullable <Enum> even though our property is null-able)  My example was just from connecting to an SQL Server test DB. It should not require any schema changes on your end.

Please check this: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/34382
